# Scrape Table Using Scrapy

Tags: python, html-table, scrapy

apologies for the long post -

I have a table that I am trying to dig into using scrapy, but can't quite figure out how to dig into this table deep enough.

This is the table:

```
<table class="detail-table" border="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tbody>
 <tr id="trAnimalID">
  ...
 </tr>
 <tr id="trSpecies">
  ...
 </tr>
 <tr id="trBreed">
  ...
 </tr>
 <tr id="trAge">
  ...
 <tr id="trSex">
  ...
 </tr>
 <tr id="trSize">
  ...
 </tr>
 <tr id="trColor">
  ...
 </tr>
 <tr id="trDeclawed">
  ...
 </tr>
 <tr id="trHousetrained">
  ...
 </tr>
 <tr id="trLocation">
  ...
 </tr>
 <tr id="trIntakeDate">
  <td class="detail-label" align="right">
   <b>Intake Date</b>
  </td>
  <td class="detail-value">
   <span id="lblIntakeDate">3/31/2020</span>&nbsp;
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="trStage">
  <td class="detail-label" align="right">
   <b>Stage</b>
  </td>
  <td class="detail-value">
   <span id="lblStage">Reserved</span>
  </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody></table>
```

I can dig into it using the scrapy shell command:

```
text = response.xpath('//*[@class="detail-table"]//tr')[10].extract()
```

I am getting back this:

```
'<tr id="trIntakeDate">\r\n\t
  <td class="detail-label" align="right">\r\n
   <b>Intake Date</b>\r\n
  </td>\r\n\t
  <td class="detail-value">\r\n
   <span id="lblIntakeDate">3/31/2020</span>\xa0\r\n
  </td>\r\n
</tr>'
```

I can't quite figure out how to just get the value for lblIntakeDate. I just need **3/31/2020**. Additionally, I'd like to run this as a lambda, and can't quite figure out how to get the execute function to dump out a json file like I can using command line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
//table[@class='detail-table']/tbody//tr/td/span[@id='lblIntakeDate']/text()
```

Go https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-tester-online.php
And please remove redundant characters such as `&nbsp;`

[image: xpath_online_tester]

Comment: This pulled me in the right direction. The query you posted wasn't pulling anything back, but I sliced in text() and it worked!


This is what I was able to get working:


`text = response.xpath('//*[@id="lblIntakeDate"]/text()').extract()`


Thanks for your help and for linking that query editor!

Comment: @MikeSimpson You are most welcome, I am happy that it could help, Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = ''
html = urlopen(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')

for i in bs.find_all('a'):
    print(i.get_text())
```